# save js object in storage by reference

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I know the way to store js objects like this:

```
    localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

    // Retrieve the object from storage
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

The only problem that it is not saved by reference.
There is a solution to this?

i want to be able to do this for example:

```
  var user = {name: "name"};
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

    var retrievedUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    var userFromSession = JSON.parse(retrievedUser );

 (user === userFromSession ) IS TRUE
```

Comment: "saved by reference": what do you mean by this?

Comment: also, what is the problem you're trying to solve in this manner?

Comment: Still dont understand the question...

Comment: eval(localStorage.getItem('testObject')) ;)

Comment: is there a reason you must compare for equality in this way? surely you could use some sort of identifier?

Comment: I want them to set to same location in memory, you dont know what is it store by reference? if something change in one of them so the other changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference in the way you are speaking of it (===) is a pointer to a location in memory. You can not serialize and deserialize an object and expect it to have the same object pointer.

When you serialize something you create a **new string** object representation of it, and when you deserialize you create a **new object**, with its own reference pointer, which is based on the content of the JSON string.

Comment: Thanks. there is any way to this in another way?

Comment: @student1001 that depends on whether you really need to know if they occupy the same place in memory or if you can come up with another acceptable definition of "equals"

Comment: To expand on the answer by @aw04. Your object only has a single property 'name', so you could assume that if `new.name == old.name` then they are equal - but they will **never** be the same single object.

Comment: Exactly, and if name is not good enough you might consider adding an id or something

Comment: It's also worth noting that === acts differently when referring to non-complex types, in which case it will return true if the objects have equal value **and** are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control memory in JavaScript, so there's no direct answer to this.

A common way to solve this is with IDs

```
function randomId(){ return Math.floor(Math.random()*1e10) }

// mapping of ids to user objects
var _users = {};

// creates a user and assigns a random id
function createUser(params){
  params.id = randomId();
  _users[params.id] = params;
  return params;
}

var user = createUser({name: 'foo'});
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
var userFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

if (user.id === userFromStorage.id) {
  // ...
}
```

Or you can see if an existing user object exists with that id

```
if (_users[userFromStorage.id]) {
   // set it to the existing user object
   // you may wish to merge the objects, but I left that out
   userFromStorage = _users[userFromStorage.id];

}
else {
   // otherwise add it to the cache
   _users[userFromStorage.id] = userFromStorage;
}
```

Now modifying `userFromStorage.name` will change `user.name`.